# Persist passed routing data on page refresh

Tags: angular

I have passed an array of objects between routes using state. But if I refresh the page I am losing data. Is there any way to persist data other than storing it in localStorage.

Comment: what type of data are you trying to persist?

Comment: @chrismclarke an array of objects ex: persons: Persons[]
where a Person is an object having variables as 
id, name, age, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data you want to persist, you can likely use either route params or query params. See examples here:
https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-in-the-activatedroute-service
and
https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments

Comment: Yeah query-parameters is good but I don't want to change the appearance of  URL because of this Object and which might be huge as well and thanks for the response Chris

Comment: Yeah I was going to say that wouldn't make sense for large objects. In that case I would suggest either local storage or persisting some sort of token that could be used to pull the rest of the data from a database. Out of interest, what is the opposition to local storage?

Answer (score 0):

It would cost you some bandwidth and speed, but you can communicate with some back end service like a database, JWTs or server caching to store the object information. Local storage will only store strings. So you will need to create tiny logic to serialize and deserialize the object. It's also harder to protect sensitive information in local storage.

Either way, there is some manner of inconvenience you will just have to decide on.

Comment: Yes we can hit backend or else we can use JWT token to serialise and deserialise but we can use @‘Input @‘Output @‘ViewChild ....... for parent to child components right? .... I need similar functionality using routes as well .... like if we store some data for parent route .... all the child route components can access that data or vice versa and thank you for your suggestion @devBrandon

Comment: I would only use the input properties for simple cases. For routes, I don't have an idea of how nested these components get, but typically its easier to use an observable data service.

Basically, create a singleton Angular service that stores a subject as a private variable. This ensures this data service owns the data. The service should have a public "Observable" variable. Now you can inject this service into any component and have access to the same data.

I created a small code example demonstrating passing data via service.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kwran